# Upload file to s3 using presigned post url in the server

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**TDLR:** Using s3 presigned post url to upload file to s3. Works fine on the browser but fails on the server.

---

I have a simple lambda function that generates presigned post url that can be consumed either in the browser or in the server.

During testing I noticed that the upload works fine one the browser but fails if I try to upload a file from a server even tho the code is identical.

The error i get is:

```
You must provide the Content-Length HTTP header
```

Detailed error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>MissingContentLength</Code>
    <Message>You must provide the Content-Length HTTP header.</Message>
    <RequestId>JP75YMFARK0G3X5Z</RequestId>
    <HostId>toHsKmxmVYYAtac94cQoy8wXoregKG3PNBm97c3gQewEmKxLggcumTAP882T/pJNWx/lxRgH98A=</HostId>
</Error>
Request failed with status code 411
```

I checked online and found many threads about this issue but unfortunately not a single suggestion helped me.

Code I am running in the server

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const { createReadStream, readFileSync } = require('fs');
const FormData = require('form-data');

const getPostPresignedUrl = async () => {
  var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: LAMBDA_GET_URL,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
      key: 'test-2.jpg',
      fileType: 'image/jpeg',
    }),
  };

  const {
    data: { data },
  } = await axios(config);

  return data;
};

const uploadFileToS3 = async (fields, url) => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  Object.entries(fields).map(([key, value]) => {
    formData.append(key, value);
  });

  const file = createReadStream('./test-1.jpg');

  formData.append('file', file);

  try {
    const { data } = await axios({
      url,
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      data: formData,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof axios.AxiosError) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};

const init = async () => {
  const { fields, url } = await getPostPresignedUrl();
  await uploadFileToS3(fields, url);
};

init();
```

Code I am running in the browser:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
      const input = document.getElementById('file');
      const getPostPresignedUrl = async (name) => {
        var config = {
          method: 'post',
          url: LAMBDA_GET_URL,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          data: JSON.stringify({
            key: name,
            fileType: 'image/jpeg',
          }),
        };

        const {
          data: { data },
        } = await axios(config);

        return data;
      };

      const uploadFileToS3 = async (fields, url, file) => {
        const formData = new FormData();

        Object.entries(fields).map(([key, value]) => {
          formData.append(key, value);
        });

        formData.append('file', file);

        try {
          const { data } = await axios({
            url,
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
            data: formData,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          if (error instanceof axios.AxiosError) {
            console.log(error.response.data);
          }
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      };

      const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const file = input.files[0];

        const data = await getPostPresignedUrl(file.name);

        await uploadFileToS3(data.fields, data.url, file);
      };

      form.onsubmit = handleSubmit;
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Content-Length` header to your upload?

Comment: The [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) package appears to have its own `submit` method that populates Content-Length. See the `form.submit` example in the README.

Comment: yes, I did add content-length but unfortunately it didn't work. @jarmod form.submit works but is there a wayt to get it working with axios?